# How to overlay a box with included lstlisting

Tags: overlays

i wanna have this block appear by tapping next.

```
\begin{block}{Methode}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i in range(2,N):
    a[i] = (a[i-1] * b + 1) % m
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}
```

i tried it with

```
\onslide<2->{ CODE }
```

but i get this error message

```
(no line number in this file):
Package utf8x Error: Character159appearedalone.

See the utf8x package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.23   \item<4->m sollte groß und eine Potenz von 10 oder 2 sein
Characters128-191areonlyallowedasargumentstocharacters194-244
```

thanks for your help =)

Comment: A `lstlisting` environment can never appear as the argument to another command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always post complete documents showing all packages used.

You can use `\pause`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{block}{Methode}
\pause
\begin{lstlisting}
for i in range(2,N):
    a[i] = (a[i-1] * b + 1) % m
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```